Step response of a tricky RC circuit
This question was asked in an interview. The circuit is given below.

The initial voltage across the capacitors is 3V each. Need to plot Vx vs time.
My response is given below. But the panel told my answer is wrong.

Can someone help me with the correct waveform.

Since you are asked to plot "over time" then can you see anything there that might alter Vx  over time? Or do you see nothing except that Vx  should stay the same?

I can see a resistor that can discharge Vx

Your answer is clearly correct, you just used a very narrow time span!

@Confused Yeah. You showed what happens at $t=0$. But then didn't show anything more (except a very zoomed-up view, perhaps?) I think they wanted you to have a sense of RC time constants. In this case, you'd have to understand what two capacitors in series "look like" to that time constant, as well. So it's asking for a few basic bits of knowledge on your part. What was the job about and what's your background? (Or, put another way, should they have expected you to handle this problem?)

I am a hardware design engineer.Mainly working in Analog circuit design(Board level).They expected me to answer this question.If you don't mind could you please provide a detailed answer.That will help me to understand these type of circuits more

@Confused Okay. And yes, you should have been able to say something then. Perhaps like: "The capacitors will combine as if they are 2/3rds of a Farad, the RC time constant is then 2/3rds of a second, and so I'd expect the voltage across the resistor to reach 0 V after 5 time constants or about 3 1/3 second." Shortened that to the answer they wanted, not the extra.

@periblepsis You're hired.

@Confused You should be able to spot cases like this, though, where one of the capacitors (the 1 F capacitor) might experience a voltage reversal during discharge. The voltage across the resistor will drop to 0 V at some point and then there will be no more current through it. But this does not mean the two capacitors are now discharged. They may retain a charge at the end of time when there is no current, anymore. And it's possible for a polarity reversal.

@Confused To spot this, just notice that the current is everywhere the same in this "discharging" circuit loop. The current through the 1 F capacitor has a different impact on its voltage, over time, than the same current does through the 2 F capacitor during the same time period. So you should expect to see the 2 F capacitor with +1 V on it while the 1 F capacitor will have -1 V, at the end of time. (The 2 F capacitor voltage changes half as fast. So once it goes from +3 V to +1 V, the 1 F capacitor will have gone from +3 V to -1 V.)

I have a question about discharge path. Will The discharge current through the resistor is flowing through the source to GND.

@Confused No. There will be zero current through the voltage source. What would be the circuit there? It can't happen. That's something else you should be able to immediately say, should someone ask that.

With this type of circuit, I always look at the variables for $t=0$ and when $t$ approaches infinity. In between, you see the two caps in series discharging from 6 V to  0 V in the 1-Ohm resistance. The answer from periblepsis is well documented.

The question you were asked is quite good. Some applicants will simply fail the question in some way. Like you did. Others will give a correct answer but not recognize anything beyond the obvious asked by the question. Still others will go further and say something more that will make them "stand out in a crowd." And the extra things that can be said, or asked, about this circuit are myriad. So it's really pretty good. I may have to steal it. ;)
The circuit, at \$t= 0\$, looks like:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
There is a circuit loop present there. It's the loop formed by \$C_1\$, \$C_2\$, and \$R_1\$. (There is no circuit loop involving \$V_1\$, so no current in \$V_1\$.)
By inspection, you can see that there is \$6\:\text{V}\$ across \$R_1\$ at \$t=0\$. This means that a current through \$R_1\$ must exist at \$t=0\$. But this current is everywhere the same in the circuit loop. So the same current found in \$R_1\$ will also be found going equally through \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$.
So there will be some manner of change in the voltages across each capacitor for some time, until such time as the voltage across \$R_1\$ is effectively zero. (It's never exactly zero, but gets arbitrarily close to zero for all intents and purposes.)
The above circuit is what I'd see, immediately. And I think you also saw it, too. But you didn't recognize that \$V_x\$ would change. I don't know why you didn't think about it. But apparently you didn't consider the change over time that they wanted to see from you.
I would have taken out a piece of paper and marked a place \$+5\,\tau\$ out on the x-axis, after first computing \$\tau=R_1\cdot\frac{C_1\,C_2}{C_1+C_2}=\frac23\:\text{s}\$. Then I would have marked on the y-axis a point at \$+3\:\text{V}\$ and \$+9\:\text{V}\$ (point A). I would then mark a point \$+3\:\text{V}\$ above \$+5\,\tau\$ (point B). Now I would draw out an RC decay from A to B, making sure to hit about 37% (about 1/3rd) of the way above \$+3\:\text{V}\$, between that and the \$+9\:\text{V}\$ value at \$+1\,\tau\$. Also then about 1/8th of the way above at \$+2\,\tau\$. The rest would have been more freehand. Like this:

(It is hard to draw with a table mouse! My pen tablet is elsewhere right now.)
But something else would have caught my attention. The differing sizes of the two capacitors. Sure, I can combine them like I did, above, for the purposes of the question at hand. But another question would have intruded, as well. What would the final voltages on them be?
I'd quickly see that one is twice the size of the other, so that the current would have to yield a rate of change for \$C_1\$ that is twice as fast as that for \$C_2\$. (This is what the basic capacitor equation says.) So then I'd think, "Hmm. Both start with the same voltage across them, but one changes twice as fast as the other one. Since I know at the end of time there will be no current in \$R_1\$ then their sum must be zero. But what about their final values?"
Then I'd think, "Well, on average they will each lose 3 V. But that's an average. What would average to 3 V but where one change is twice the other?" And then I'd know. It must be a \$4\:\text{V}\$ change on one of them and a \$2\:\text{V}\$ change on the other one. Of course, the smaller change would be on the larger one, \$C_2\$. So then I'd know that the final voltages will be \$C_1\$ with \$+3\:\text{V}-4\:\text{V}=-1\:\text{V}\$ and \$C_2\$ with \$+3\:\text{V}-2\:\text{V}=+1\:\text{V}\$.
And then I'd be able to quip something about the fact that, at the end, one of these large capacitors would have a reversal of polarity and that this might be a concern.
It also provides me with the tools I may need should they then decide to ask about the voltages across the capacitors.
This question allows an interviewee to say more than just what the question asks. And they could also follow up and ask what you asked, which is whether or not there would be a current in the voltage source. (No.) Just to see if the interviewee shows any confusion about that, as well.
It is a good question. Simple and allowing simple answers. But complex enough to allow someone who sees further to show them they do. I like it.
